# MYSQL "SELECT CASE" view syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

I have a couple of views which use the SELECT CASE syntax.However when I create a back up scripts and try restoring I get syntax errors.Keep in mind however the view was sucessfully created in the first place.

On of my several "SELECT CASE" syntax view is right here

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v_stockmovement` ;
CREATE VIEW `v_stockmovement`   
AS
SELECT stock_mov.id AS ID,
stock_category.stock_category_code AS categorycode,
stock_mov_type,
(SELECT CASE stock_mov_type 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Stock Issue' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'Stock Reorder'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Stock Adjustment'
ELSE '' END) AS stock_mov_typedesc,
(SELECT stock_mov_unitcost * stock_mov_quantity) AS cost,
stock_mov_comments
FROM stock_mov
INNER JOIN stock ON stock.stock_code = stock_mov.stock_mov_linkstockcode
INNER JOIN stock_category ON stock_category.stock_category_code = stock.stock_linkcategory
;
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: `(SELECT CASE stock_mov_type  ... ELSE '' END) AS stock_mov_typedesc` should just be `CASE stock_mov_type  ... ELSE '' END AS stock_mov_typedesc` and `(SELECT stock_mov_unitcost * stock_mov_quantity) AS cost` should be `stock_mov_unitcost * stock_mov_quantity AS cost`. What error are you getting?

Comment: @MartinSmith You should've written this as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Romain - I have no explanation for why the OP says it works previously though.

Comment: @MartinSmith Probably because the case that "previously worked" actually had the `CASE` as the first column of the resultset, and thus enjoyed the presence of a pretty well-placed `SELECT` as the first word of the query?

Comment: @MartinSmith just saw your comment after typing the same as an answer. You should get a +1 for being fast

Comment: @Romain - It would be valid in SQL Server as treated as a sub query that references columns from the outer query so not actually sure that this is the source of the OP's problems either but either way would be clearer to get rid of the extra `SELECT`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: (I've removed the brackets and the SELECT around the CASE statement)

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v_stockmovement` ;
CREATE VIEW `v_stockmovement`   
AS
SELECT stock_mov.id AS ID,
stock_category.stock_category_code AS categorycode,
stock_mov_type,
CASE stock_mov_type 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Stock Issue' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Stock Reorder'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Stock Adjustment'
  ELSE '' 
END stock_mov_typedesc,
stock_mov_unitcost * stock_mov_quantity AS cost,
stock_mov_comments
FROM stock_mov
INNER JOIN stock ON stock.stock_code = stock_mov.stock_mov_linkstockcode
INNER JOIN stock_category ON stock_category.stock_category_code = stock.stock_linkcategory
;
```

Comment: So what does `SELECT stock_mov_unitcost * stock_mov_quantity` in the `SELECT` actually do? It's a bit odd a way to put things... (I know it's in the OP, but I suspect it's a cause of trouble)

Comment: @Romain agree. I just saw it after posting and did already edit the answer.